# truncate autocomplete value based on maxlength @html.textboxfor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can I truncate selected value from autocomplete search into the @html.textboxfor. for example, I set the maxlength = 10. Therefore, as per picture below, result only print '205000000 ' instead of whole value.

[image]

Comment: Have your autocomplete results given by certain database query? Better to post autocomplete code in your question (both server-side and client-side).

Comment: yes, all value came from DB.  i'm using below script to pass data   <br/>        
        var availableTags = JSON.parse('@ViewBag.Data');
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });   @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: By mentioning `JSON.parse('@ViewBag.Data')`, it means autocomplete results passed through `ViewBag.Data` property. You may use foreach loop after query to iterate through results => truncate values to 10 characters => use `Distinct()` method to remove dupe values before passing into `ViewBag.Data` (better to show what already done in server-side query).